# Map SQL table rows to C++ structures

Tags: c++, sqlite, serialization

I'm trying to implement some kind of persistent storage of C++ structures into an SQLite database. It looks nice in the beginning but then it becomes complicated with all those SQL requests, data binds and manual getting field values one after another.

Ideally I'd like to have some kind of mapping from a table row in SQLite to a C++ structure, with a possibility of running SQL requests on that. On the other hand, I'd still like to keep it general enough to be able to run more complex requests with joins etc.

I even thought that an external utility that would auto-generate the corresponding C++/SQL glue code could be helpful.

What would be the right way to do this kind of mapping? I've heard people suggesting boost::serialization or Google's protocol buffers, would this be a *much* better option for what I want, or maybe there are some other good options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want an Object Relational Mapper (ORM).  Try reading through this stack overflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141/good-orm-for-c-solutions

The selected answer there talks about [Database Template Library](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/); I'd look into there as well.

Comment: This is indeed very relevant, thanks! Though, it seems that these ORM systems tend to take complete control over the database, while I'd still like to have the ability to run custom SQL requests, not limited to those the library is based on.

Answer (score 1):

[Soci](http://soci.sourceforge.net) is a good start. If it doesn't meet all your needs, it will help you figure out where you want to go.

I used it for a while with sqlite, and found it better than the others I could find. I did end up writing my own, though ...